# What is difference between name and display name of a network interface?

Tags: java, sockets, ubuntu-16.04, network-interface

I am using java 8 on ubuntu 16.04. The class java.net.NetworkInterface has two methods for Interface name. First one is:

```
Get the name of this network interface.
Returns:
    the name of this network interface

     public String  [More ...] getName() {
             return name;
     }
```

Other one is:

```
Get the display name of this network interface. A display name is a human readable String describing the network device. 
 Returns:
   the display name of this network interface, or null if no display name is available.

 public String  [More ...] getDisplayName() {
            return displayName;
 }
```

When I do ifconfig, the output is:

```
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:1d:6e:03:42  
          inet addr:10.100.14.40  Bcast:10.100.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc60:10a7:2f7e:127f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:30338414 errors:0 dropped:31 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:446227 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3188550996 (3.1 GB)  TX bytes:53620407 (53.6 MB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:fc500000-fc520000
```

Only one name is shown. If I run following program:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class MyNetworkInterface
{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
                Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
                while(interfaces.hasMoreElements())
                {
                        NetworkInterface n = (NetworkInterface) interfaces.nextElement();
                        System.out.println(n);
                        System.out.printf("the Name is: %s%n", n.getDisplayName());
                        System.out.printf("the Name: %s%n", n.getName());
                }
        }
```

}

The output is:

```
name:enp0s25 (enp0s25)
the Name is: enp0s25
the Name: enp0s25
name:lo (lo)
the Name is: lo
the Name: lo
```

Both names are same.

My question is:
What is difference between name and display name of a network interface? Why two names are used?

Comment: Maybe the difference exists only on some platforms, eg iirc on Windows you can give a network interface a name. Maybe that is what is shown for displayName.